# InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS in Samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

In my app, I have an `EditText`, with a button to change the keyboard input type. The code:

```
ToggleCambiarTeclado.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (ToggleCambiarTeclado.isChecked()) {

            tipoDeTecladoActual = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
            imagenTeclado.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_numeric));
        } else {
            tipoDeTecladoActual = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
            imagenTeclado.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_querty));

        }
        editNumeroContador.setInputType(tipoDeTecladoActual);
    }
});
```

It works perfectly in my phone...but my boss has a Samsung, and is not changing the keyboard type in his phone.

I have tried changing it to `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL`, `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` and `YPE_CLASS_TEXT`, neither of them are working.

Anyone knows if this is a bug? Any known workaround?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Just realized my boss has TouchPal installed. If he changes the default keyboard to the standard it works perfectly...

Answer (score 5):

Later Samsung devices have SwiftKey keyboards built in.  SwiftKey intentionally decided at some point to ignore Android's `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`.

A workaround is to use `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`, which is somewhat hacky, but an unfortunately common workaround.

XML variant: `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`

Comment: This works on Samsung, but breaks Korean input. With "visible password", the Google Korean keyboard is showing latin symbols only.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's behave weirdly with most things. I've had this issue before and I seem to recall that changing the input type to email worked like a charm. Give it a try.