# why TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS is not working to disable auto corrections?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a TextEdit where the user can enter their name. I do not want the editor to auto-correct spelling mistakes. I try to do :

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

but this didn't do anything. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` and `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` are static variables belonging to `InputType` class.
You have to use them as follows:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

**EDIT:** As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33227237/10487248), some keyboards ignore `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`. So using `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` is a common workaround which you said you've already implemented.

Comment: Thanks, but it's was already the case, i just wrote the code a little to fastly here :(

Comment: Add some more code if possible. It's impossible to help with what you've provided as it seems right. The problem must be somewhere else. Add your xml as well as relevant Java code.

Comment: I do not have any other code :( it's a pretty simple code, I do now use XML as i create the TextEdit inside the code. if I do myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD); then it's work but I do not understand why i must add InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD

Comment: @loki, You need to account that not all keyboards honor the TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS flag. Even if it works for you, there will be thousands of users with different keyboards where this flag is ignored. The workaround is to also include the TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD flag, because passwords "cannot / must not" have suggestions, and as it is supported by all keyboards, such flag will produce your expected behavior in all devices.